# Press the next button in google search result

Tags: r, selenium

I try to click to go to the next page of search results of google using the following code:

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
checkForServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*/input[@id = 'lst-ib']")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("R Cran", "\uE007"))
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#pnnext")
click <- webElem$getElementAttribute("href")
remDr$clickElement(click)
```

However I receive the following error:

```
Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) : 
  ‘clickElement’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “remoteDriver”
```

Does click next button to google search results has different code?

Using inspect I can see that the source code for the button is:

```
<a id="pnnext" class="pn" style="text-align:left" href="/search?q=R+Cran&biw=1366&bih=657&ei=szhxVv_NMaHMygPW4pLQDg&start=10&sa=N">
```

Finally what was worked for me:

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
checkForServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*/input[@id = 'lst-ib']")
Sys.sleep(5)
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("R Cran", "\uE007"))
Sys.sleep(5)
link <- remDr$executeScript("return document.getElementById('pnnext').href;")
remDr$navigate(link[[1]])
```

Comment: Try this xpath .//*[@id='pnnext']/span[2]

Comment: @Shah I tried this `webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", ".//*[@id='pnnext']/span[2]")` but I take this error `Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
   Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to "click" an attribute/string, which is not working the way you try it.

On this line you are grabbing a link as a string (which is not a WebElement for Selenium!)

```
click <- webElem$getElementAttribute("href")
```

and then in the next line you are trying to click this link/string via a method that actually needs a WebElement

```
remDr$clickElement(click)
```

So here is what you can try:

1) you could try to click your last WebElement directly (not doing the `getAttribute`):

```
webElem$clickElement()
```

or

2) you could try to navigate to the link you just got through `getAttribute`:

```
click <- webElem$getElementAttribute("href")
// change your last line to this
remDr$navigate(click)
```

Comment: Thank you. You gave e and idea to take first the link I want to go with a different way. I have updated my question with the workaround I used.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what client are you using but it might be that you need to wait() until the ajax request finishes. visibilityOfElementLocated #pnext